# How to calculate Godambe information matrix in R?

Tags: r, mle, hessian-matrix

I have a likelihood function in R that I am optimizing using 'optim' and calculating the hessian matrix using hessian=T in the optim function. I want to calculate the Godambe Information matrix in R, which is defined as:

G(theta)= H(theta) J(theta)^-1 H(theta)

where J(theta) is the variability matrix and H(theta) is the sensitivity matrix.

I am not sure how to calculate these matrices in R for my likelihood function and the estimates obtained from the optim. Please help.

Comment: There is a function [godambe](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/weightedScores/versions/0.9.5.3/topics/godambe) in package `weightedScores`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I checked that one but it seems that it is specific to certain likelihoods such as poisson, bernoulli and negative binomial.

Comment: Perhaps try asking this question on [Cross Validated](http://www.stats.stackexchange.com) - you'll have a better chance of getting a reliable answer, given the theme of your question.